# Catching errors from procedures outside of processing block

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I have following code (it's simplified for illustration purposes). I'm creating records in different DB tables in proc1, proc2, and proc3. What I'm trying to achieve is...if I encounter an error while looping through temp-tables at any point (even after I created a bunch of DB records already), I want to roll everything back so no records are created. It catches errors if proc1, proc2, and proc3 with no issues but I cannot figure out how to pass those errors to the main processing block so it understands it and rolls everything back. In other words, the message ('error @ main trans block') never pops up so the already created records stay in the DB. As a matter of fact, nothing gets rolled back.

```
DO TRANSACTION ON ERROR UNDO, THROW:

    FOR EACH tt1:

        RUN proc1.

        FOR EACH tt2 WHERE tt2.field1 EQ tt1.field1:

            RUN proc2.

            FOR EACH tt3 WHERE tt3.field2 EQ tt2.field2:

                RUN proc3.

            END.

        END.

    END.

    CATCH e AS PROGRESS.Lang.AppERROR:

        MESSAGE 'error @ main trans block'
            VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX INFO BUTTONS OK.

    END CATCH. 

END.

PROCEDURE proc1.
    DO TRANSACTION ON ERROR UNDO, THROW:

        /* creating some DB records */

        CATCH e AS PROGRESS.Lang.ERROR:

            RETURN ERROR 'Proc1 ' + e:getmessage(1). 

        END CATCH. 

    END.

END PROCEDURE.

PROCEDURE proc2.
    DO TRANSACTION ON ERROR UNDO, THROW:

        /* creating some DB records */

        CATCH e AS PROGRESS.Lang.ERROR:

            RETURN ERROR 'Proc2 ' + e:getmessage(1). 

        END CATCH. 

    END.

END PROCEDURE.

PROCEDURE proc3.
    DO TRANSACTION ON ERROR UNDO, THROW:

        /* creating some DB records */

        CATCH e AS PROGRESS.Lang.ERROR:

            RETURN ERROR 'Proc3 ' + e:getmessage(1). 

        END CATCH. 

    END.

END PROCEDURE.
```

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of potential issues.

First, your temp-tables tt1 and tt2 need to be defined without the `NO-UNDO` flag.

Second, the FOR EACH blocks are using their default error handling behavior, which is `ON ERROR UNDO, NEXT.` So errors raised within the FOR EACH blocks will cause the current iteration to be undone, not the whole transaction.

I recommend adding the

```
BLOCK-LEVEL ON ERROR UNDO, THROW .
```

to the top of the program. Or at least

```
ROUTINE-LEVEL ON ERROR UNDO, THROW .
```

in combination with an `ON ERROR UNDO, THROW` option on all the `FOR EACH` blocks.

The `BLOCK-LEVEL` error handling option is available since OpenEdge 11.3 (or so).

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for your suggestion. It sort of worked, but I don't think I explained this right. I added BLOCK-LEVEL at the top of the procedure and the whole procedure gets undone now. However, I only need a specific block and all of the internal procedure that this block calls undone. I would like to avoid separating this logic in a in a separate file. There surely must be a way to undo just a specific block of code and all of the code that is being called from inside of this code?

Comment: That's what block labels can be used for. Before an (iterating) block, do something like my-label: FOR EACH .... and then UNDO, LEAVE my-label.

Comment: Hi Mike, will this approach work if I call a procedure that does something (for example, creates permanent DB records) from within an iterating block? For example..... createBlock: for each....on error undo createBlock, leave createBlock: run createProc. end.   createProc. .....create permanentDBTable. end procedure.  If I already created 10 DB records and on the 11th iteration of the FOR EACH, I have an error in createProc, will it roll back (uncreate) all of the 10 records that have been created prior?

Comment: If you have an outer transaction block and that block is the one you UNDO, LEAVE then yes

Comment: Hi Mike, alright...I'll give it a shot later. I actually split the 'update' logic into a separate external procedure and it backs out all of the updates in case of error, but I think having this logic inside of my main procedure would be more preferable still.

Comment: Hi Mike, I added block label and it worked fine. Appreciate your help!